# How to switch min and max input values based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, input

I have a two `input` elements, where I defined min and max. 
How I can reverse this values, preferably in HTML or JS (Angular).

For example:

```
<label>
    Width:
    <input type="number" min="10" max="100">
</label>

<label>
    Height:
    <input type="number" min="50" max="400">
</label>
```

If user put 400 in first input, the min and max values in second input will be replaced by `min="10" max="100"`.

In other words, values must be interchangeable.

Comment: are you using any kind of calculation for this. if any please post

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to do the job, using some extra variables and [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.minWidth = 10;
  $scope.maxWidth = 100;
  $scope.minHeight = 50;
  $scope.maxHeight = 400;
  
  $scope.update = function(v) {
    if((v == 'w' && $scope.width > $scope.maxWidth) || (v == 'h' && $scope.height > $scope.maxHeight)) {
      let reverseMax = $scope.maxWidth;
      let reverseMin = $scope.minWidth;
      $scope.maxWidth = $scope.maxHeight;
      $scope.maxHeight = reverseMax;
      $scope.minWidth = $scope.minHeight;
      $scope.minHeight = reverseMin;
    }
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<label>
    Width:
    <input type="number" 
           ng-model="width" 
           ng-change="update('w')"
           ng-min="minWidth" 
           ng-max="maxWidth">
    {{minWidth}} - {{maxWidth}}
</label>
<br/>
<label>
    Height:
    <input type="number" 
           ng-model="height" 
           ng-change="update('h')"
           ng-min="minHeight" 
           ng-max="maxHeight">
    {{minHeight}} - {{maxHeight}}

</label>
</div>
```